# Implementing a mongodb aggregation pipeline in c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have mongdb 'aggregation query' containing eight steps, that I can run in the console and in RoboMongo successfully.

```
db.getCollection("...").aggregate([
    {$match: { ... } },
    {$unwind: ... },
    {$project: { ... } },
    {$group: { ... } },
    {$project: { ... } },
    {$unwind: ... },
    {$group: { ... } }
])
```

Now is the time to get this thing running inside my asp.net app, but I struggle heavily with the implementation in c#.

The new aggregation framework looks promising, but I don't want to define every intermediate type through the pipeline, and as far as I can see, it doesn't work without it.

So the question is:
**Is it possible to use the aggregation framework without defining each intermediate type?**

and secondly,
**What would be the best way of implementing existing queries like this?**

I see the framework contains multiple ways of defining the aggregation pipeline, like different `PipelineDefinition` implementations and the extension methods, but I find little documentation and use of these.

Comment: All the C# driver will be doing is compiling your C# query into the aforementioned MongoDB query. Why not pass this query straight to MongoDB? It would save a lot of angst and be a lot simpler.

Comment: yes, I've been thinking about that myself.. But I have now something that pretty much do what I want, but it involves a heavy load of intermediate types.

Comment: IMHO, always go for the simplest possible solution. As far as maintainability goes, adding an extra C# layer, just to get something into C#, may not be the best approach. And there is a small chance that if they change the C# driver, it suddenly might change behavior or run 100x slower, so it's a bit of a lottery that way in any case.

Comment: What disappoints me, though, is that the new aggregation framework is this hard to work with... Looks like it's the `$unwind` command that trips everything. Removing that, and everything works quite ok with anonymous types...

Comment: Perhaps submit an issue on the MongoDB Jira portal? The C# driver guys are actually pretty good at incorporating feedback into the next version. See http://jira.mongodb.org/.

Comment: Apparently, the next version 2.1 adds better support for Aggregations: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP/fixforversion/14580/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the next version 2.1 of the C# driver will add better support for Aggregations, see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-935.

The full list of changes for 2.1 is at  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP/fixforversion/14580/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel.

I would recommend adding your use case at http://jira.mongodb.org/, the C# driver guys are quite responsive.